# ld command on OSX

Tags: c++, macos, linker, ld

I wanted to use a Dynamic shared library ".so" file using ld command on Mac OS X.

I'm able to compile without errors and create the file using

---

```
ld -dynamic -dylib -arch x86_64 -macosx_version_min 10.10.0 -o libpacket.so obj/SpectrumClient.o obj/socket.o obj/packetCounters.o -lSystem /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/clang/6.1.0/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.osx.a
```

---

To check the file generated is for OS X..

~ vamsi$ file libpacket.so

libpacket.so: Mach-O 64-bit dynamically linked shared library x86_64

---

To allow ld to search for this I move the .so file to 
/usr/lib
(I get error "ld: library not found for -lpacket" when I don't do so.)

To check if this works I run the command

```
ld -lpacket -v
```

I get the following error:

---

```
@(#)PROGRAM:ld  PROJECT:ld64-242
configured to support archs: i386 x86_64 x86_64h armv6 armv7 armv7s armv7m armv7k arm64
Library search paths:
    /usr/lib
    /usr/local/lib
Framework search paths:
    /Library/Frameworks/
    /System/Library/Frameworks/
ld: warning: -arch not specified
ld: warning: -macosx_version_min not specified, assuming 10.6
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "start", referenced from:
     implicit entry/start for main executable
ld: symbol(s) not found for inferred architecture x86_64
```

---

I'm running on updated OS X (10.10.5)

Even though I'm specifying the architecture and Minimum OS X version why am I getting the error? 
I know I don't have start function in this .so file, but when I link this in other the functions are not linked.
Can someone point out the mistake I'm doing?

Thank you.

Comment: Where is your shared lib .so from? The error sounds like using a linux-.so on Mac, and I'm quite sure that won't work.

Comment: @flaschenpost.. Please note that the .so file is generated on this system using ld command (please look at the first command in the post..)  
The .o files are generated compiled on same system.   

I have edited the post to show that the .so file generated is of Mach-0 file not ELF (or linux based).

Comment: FYI, this isn't the root of your problem, but MacOSX / Darwin has different behavior when searching for dynamic libraries than Linux does. Each dylib has an *install name* set by the `-install_name` linker flag. This path is stored in the dylib, and when something is linked against it, the path is copied into the referencing file and eventually used to find the dylib at load time. See the `dyld` man page for more info. This is unlike Linux, where it's normal to put your dylibs in specific directories like `/usr/lib` and refer to them only by their basename.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the issue with why the project wasn't able to link the .so file.

While compiling ".so" file, have additional config

-DTARGET_OS_MAC

Now I don't get the error "Can't find the method..." while linking the .so file to the other project.

@KenThomases.. You were right about "ld -lpacket -v" command not giving any useful information. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

`ld` interprets your command `ld -lpacket` as a request to link a complete program executable from the object files in the specified library. That would make most sense if `packet` referred to a static library.

In any case, your library isn't sufficient to build a complete executable. The linker is implicitly looking for a `start` routine and not finding it. The `start` routine would not normally be in your code, it would be in the C runtime library. When you use the compiler to drive the link step, the compiler specifies the C runtime library, which provides `start`. However, the C runtime library then has a dependency on your code providing a `_main` symbol, so that just moves the problem one step along.

In short, `ld -lpacket` is not a sensible link command. You can't link just a dynamic library. What is it being linked **to**? What did you expect that command to accomplish?

The other stuff about `-arch` and `-macosx_version_min` not being specified is about **this** link command. The fact that you specified them when building the library is irrelevant. For this invocation of the linker, you're forcing the linker to guess what you intend, so it's telling you what it guessed.

Comment: I'm trying to link this dynamic library  to another project with make file.. Since the error isn't being printed while make command..I was testing whether ld command is able to read the .so file using "ld -lpacket -v" command.

I'm not worried about the start routine. Its the methods that were compiled using the source code..even though other functions are being declared in code used to build the .so file. the project fails giving the error saying that ld can't find the given methods..

its this error "symbol(s) not found for inferred architecture x86_64" which I'm not able to understand why.

Comment: In simple terms..I have a method "void hello()" in packethello.c which is compiled to form the .o file with which this libpacket.so file is created. I have another testing_hello.c file which calls this "hello()" method and they are linked though ld command. When I run the testing_hello.c I get error that hello() is not found..

Comment: If you're trying to link your test program and getting errors, show the command you used to try to link that test program (e.g. `cc -o testing_hello testing_hello.c -lpacket`) and those errors. The command "ld -lpacket" is useless for testing anything. Its results are meaningless. (By the way, dynamic shared libraries are not called .so on OS X. They are called .dylib. But that isn't really important to the results you're seeing.)

Comment: /usr/bin/c++  -fPIC -O3 -DNDEBUG   -shared -Wl,-soname,libgnuradio-db.so -o libgnuradio-db.so CMakeFiles/gnuradio-db.dir/db_src_impl.cc.o CMakeFiles/gnuradio-db.dir/db_sink_impl.cc.o CMakeFiles/gnuradio-db.dir/data_impl.cc.o -lboost_filesystem -lboost_system /usr/local/lib/libgnuradio-runtime.so /usr/local/lib/libgnuradio-pmt.so -lpacket -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/lib:


This command is generated using CMake file.